# How to return to Mac OS X snow leopard from lion on other partition?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I've created another partition and installed Lion on one. Lion is good, but not enough.

**So the question is, how can I return to Snow Leopard on the other partition and completly delete Lion?**

Comment: And for clarity, do you want to downgrade Lion to Snow Leopard? If so, the answer is no. There isn't an Apple support way to downgrade. And if there are user created methods (which I haven't seen on any previous OS), Lion isn't mature enough for people to have tested and verified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete its partition in Disk Utility when booted into Snow Leopard. You should be able to enlarge the SL partition again.